# How can I pre-populate a simple class with data?

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public class TextFiller
{
    public HtmlText Text { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

public class HtmlText { 
    [AllowHtml]
    public string TextWithHtml { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I change the class so that when I do the following it creates a TextFiller instance with TEXT populated with "" and Details populated with "" ?

I assume constructors but I am still learning and would appreciate help. In particular I am confused because I suppose I need to have a constructor for HtmlText also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already guessed, you can set the initial values of properties from within a constructor:

```
public class TextFiller
{
    public TestFiller()
    {
        Text = new HtmlText();
        Details = "";
    }

    public HtmlText Text { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

public class HtmlText
{ 
    public HtmlText()
    {
        TextWithHtml = "";
    }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string TextWithHtml { get; set; } 
}
```

See also: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Comment: Thank. I will mark this correct as I realize you have a constructor for HtmlText also.